# Read CSV from API with ogr2ogr

Tags: csv, ogr2ogr, api

I'm trying to convert a CSV to PostgreSQL with ogr2ogr, but the CSV is coming from an API:

```
http://api.statbank.dk/v1/data/FT/CSV?delimiter=Semicolon&HOVEDDELE=*&Tid=*
```

I have tried following ogr2ogr:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname=postgres host=localhost port=5432 user=postgres password=xxx" CSV:"http://api.statbank.dk/v1/data/FT/CSV?delimiter=Semicolon&HOVEDDELE=*&Tid=*" -nln FT -lco SEPARATOR=SEMICOLON
```

But are getting

```
Unable to open datasource `CSV:http://api.statbank.dk/v1/data/FT/CSV?delimiter=Semicolon&HOVEDDELE=*&Tid=*' with the following drivers.....
```

I can get it working if I download the CSV and use ogr2ogr, but would prefer to fetch it straight from the API to reduce the steps in my script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Addition due to comments**

Using `/vsicurl_streaming/` and `CSV:` before works. You can try using the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" fake.shp CSV:"/vsicurl_streaming/http://api.statbank.dk/v1/data/FT/CSV?delimiter=Semicolon&HOVEDDELE=*&Tid=*"
```

**First answer**

It seems it's not possible. According to some tests, GDAL can't guess correctly the file input format from the API endpoint provided. I didn't find a way to inform GDAL of the input format (possible?). You will see the tests I've done below (did not use PostgreSQL for output, instead use ESRI Shapefile)

- Work because OGR/GDAL guess the input format with the extension

  ```
  ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" fake.shp "/vsicurl/http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv"
  ```
- Do not work because OGR/GDAL unable to guess the input format (no extension)

  ```
  ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" fake.shp "/vsicurl/http://api.statbank.dk/v1/data/FT/CSV?delimiter=Semicolon&HOVEDDELE=*&Tid=*"
  ```

Comment: According to http://gdal.org/1.11/ogr/drv_csv.html: _Starting with GDAL 1.8.0, for files structured as CSV, but not ending with .CSV extension, the 'CSV:' prefix can be added before the filename to force loading by the CSV driver_. Tried `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" fake.shp CSV:"/vsicurl/http://api.statbank.dk/v1/data/FT/CSV?delimiter=Semicolon&HOVEDDELE=*&Tid=*"` but are getting same error.

Comment: I've tried this one but like you, it was not working the expected way for me. It does not works with remote URL maybe.

Comment: Even Rouault from got it working by using `/vsicurl_streaming/`. Se answer below

Comment: You should accept your own solution.

Comment: Stackexchange says that I have to wait for 6 hours before it's possible. I will accept later.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer from GDAL osgeo mailing list:**
The server doesn't seem to support range GET requests, but I see this works if 
you use the /vsicurl_streaming/ virtual file system (and CSV reading is in 
streaming, so this matches well)

```
ogrinfo  -ro CSV:"/vsicurl_streaming/http://api.statbank.dk/v1/data/FT/CSV?delimiter=Semicolon&HOVEDDELE=*&Tid=*" -al -q
```

Note that `-lco SEPARATOR=SEMICOLON` is useless. `-lco` stands for layer creation option, so this should be for the output driver, here PostgreSQL